# Serializing complex map to class with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following JSON that I'm trying to serialize into a Java class:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": [{},{},{}],
        "d1": [{},{},{}],
        ...,
        "dN": [{},{},{}]},
      ....,
      "cN": {
        "d1": [{},{},{}]}
}}}
```

Now I can easily create a class like so to represent this JSON snip:

```
public class WorldData {
    private Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Object>>>> data;

    public List<Object> getData(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        return data.get(a).get(b).get(c).get(d);
    }
}
```

and serialize directly without issue, except for the fact that I have a complex map with arbitrary values that is difficult to read. What I would much rather do is have different classes to represent each layer of the JSON so that each layer can just call the layer underneath for data. For example,

```
public class WorldData {
    private Map<String, AData> aData;

    public List<Object> getData(String a, String b, String c, String d) {
        return aData.get(a).getData(b ,c, d);
    }
}
public class AData {
    private Map<String, BData> bData;

    public List<Object> getData(String b, String c, String d) {
        return bData.get(b).getData(c, d);
    }
}
public class BData {
    private Map<String, CData> cData;

    public List<Object> getData(String c, String d) {
        return bData.get(c).getData(d);
    }
}
public class CData {
    private Map<String, DData> dData;

    public List<Object> getData(String d) {
        return bData.get(d);
    }
}
public class DData {
    private List<Object> data;
}
```

However, I'm unsure how to do force ObjectMapper to serialize the JSON to the wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use online tools, to convert json to POJO,

Your json string when converted to POJO, looks as below

```
public class D{
}

public class D1{
}

public class DN{
}

public class C{
    public List<D> d;
    public List<D1> d1;
    public List<DN> dN;
}

public class CN{
    public List<D1> d1;
}

public class B{
    public C c;
    public CN cN;
}

public class A{
    public B b;
}

public class Root{
    public A a;
}
```

you can convert json string to Java object using object mapper as below

```
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
 ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Root root = om.readValue(myJsonString), Root.class);
```

Comment: This works, but it's not what I'm looking for, as the D, D1, ..., DN notation stands that there are infinite number at those layers, which is why a Map is prefer, as stated.

Answer (score 0):

What you *could* do is to write one or more custom deserializer classes and then register them with the `ObjectMapper` instance.  This is described in many of the tutorials linked from the [Jackson Documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs) page.

However, it is unclear that using using POJO's is the best approach in your example.  Based on your example, I suspect that it would be more work to code up the custom deserializer for the `ObjectMapper` than it would be to write some utility methods for querying a tree of `JSONObject` / `JSONArray` instances.